# Logo sitting on top of navigation and header

Tags: html, css

I have a concept for the header/navigation of a (responsive) website I'm working on, but I unfortunately can't figure out how to achieve what I want in HTML/CSS in a way that will work in a responsive layout.

This is the concept I want to implement:

[image]

Essentially the logo needs to be sitting in the middle of the left and right halves of the navigation, and overlapping the header div.

Comment: Have you considered using a graphics manipulation tools (photoshop, corel painter, etc) to create the image and then overlay the menu on top of it?

Comment: I'm sorry but what is your question? I imagine that doing this is possible using CSS and HTML in a responsive manner.

Comment: @NoRush I can do that, but that will not work in a responsive layout, unless I have a number of different images of different sizes which get switched out at various different browser sizes. Obviously that's not a good solution though.

Comment: @darshanags My question is how to achieve something like what is in the above image in HTML/CSS. I am guessing it's possible to achieve this in a way that works in a responsive layout, but I just have no idea how.

Comment: You have to define first: what shall happen in your layout in the responsive manner?

Comment: hey jordan, let me know if my answer fits the bill and if not, let me know what's missing.. these answers take a while to create! :p

Comment: Jordan.. These kinds of questions are 1.very specific to the one asking them (ie there is little that others can learn from) and 2.take a while to implement. It took me well over an hour to get it done and then I even responded to your feedback.. For you to just disappear after that is NOT cool..

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/abbood/9yhHE/

(i replaced your logo image with a random image i created)
to make the nav bar appear as if it's one color.. just make sure the s and the  have zero borders and no spacing in between.. and you're good to go

**html**

```
<div id="imgContainer" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>left header text</th>
        <th>right header text</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="right">
            <ul>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
            </ul>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
#header {
    height: 3em;
    min-width: 40em;
}


table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 40em;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

table tr th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right:1em;
}

table tr th:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left:1em;
}

table ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right:0;
}



table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 3em;
}
td.right {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
}


#imgContainer {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 40em;
    background-image: url(http://s8.postimage.org/49ywsfsqp/logo.png);
    background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

note: i made the basic structure.. i lef the styling and putting spacing between the nav bar items to you (it's easy).. but the basic structure should be shound

**update**
just had to make the logo appear on top.. (did that by z-index + abs positioning)

here is the updated http://jsfiddle.net/abbood/9yhHE/2/

**html**

```
<div id="imgContainer">
    <img  src="http://s8.postimage.org/49ywsfsqp/logo.png" />
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>left header text</th>
        <th>right header text</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td class="right">
            <ul>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
                <li>nav item</li>
            </ul>   
        </td>
    </tr>



</table>
```

**css**

```
#header {
    height: 3em;
    min-width: 40em;
}


table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 40em;
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

table tr th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    padding-right:1em;
}

table tr th:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left:1em;
}

table ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right:0;
}



table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 3em;
}
td.right {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

#imgContainer {
        min-width: 40em;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;

}

#imgContainer > img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px ;
    z-index: 1; 
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if that will work in this case. As shown in the image, the navigation will have a background. When I add a background to your jsFiddle, it covers the logo: http://jsfiddle.net/9yhHE/1/

Comment: you're right! sorry man I did the first answer while i was on the bus lol.. i just updated it.. should work now

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can think of three ways to do this:

1. Use different images of different dimensions and have them placed within different layers which are displayed/hidden at different resolutions
2. Have one element (, , etc..) and have the logo as a background-image of that element, you can switch between backgrounds at different resolutions
3. Have a single sprited image with all logo sizes and change it's position using css background-position or the hard way by using margins and overflow properties.

You could also refer existing sites. A good library of responsive sites can be found here: http://mediaqueri.es